# Python for Algorithm Execution Visualization

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, paradigms

I have a very interesting assignment for class of Analysis of Algorithms, which I should make a graphic comparison of a famous problem (such as the Knapsack problem) using different approaches, such as Dynamic Programming and Greedy. I wanted to know if there is a library or a tool that I could use to help the visualization (mainly for the time complexity) in Python that I could use. The idea would be a simple graphic, such as the one shown below:

[image: Graphic]

Comment: I Think [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) will be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to calculate actual time complexity of your algorithm. This can be done either with `timeit.timeit` (the actual wall time) or by manually calculating the number of operations.

Here is an example for bubble sort algorithm:

```
def bubble_sort(a):
    not_sorted = True
    operations = 0
    while not_sorted:
        not_sorted = False
        for i in range(len(a)-1):
            operations += 1
            if a[i] > a[i+1]:
                a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
                not_sorted = True
    return operations
```

Now you can feed this function with arrays of different sizes, collect the number of operations needed each time and make a graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import sample

# assuming we are in Jupyter:
%matplotlib inline

ns = range(10, 1000, 10)
ops = []
for n in ns:
    my_list = sample(range(n), n)
    ops.append(bubble_sort(my_list))
plt.plot(ns, ops)
```

[image: graph 1]

You can even check the asymptotics with some statistics like this:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(n=ns, ops=ops))
model = ols('ops ~ n + I(n**2)', df)
model = model.fit()
plt.plot(ns, ops)
plt.plot(ns, model.predict())
```

[image: graph 2]

To find an actual wall time, just use

```
from timeit import timeit
time = timeit('bubble_sort(a)', number=10, globals=globals())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was a very clear answer that will definitely help me in this assignment!